# What is the correct way to configure Apache and Tomcat such that Apache serves HTML over port 80, and Tomcat serves ColdFusion/Railo over port 80?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, coldfusion, railo

Here is my situation:

I have a server with Apache and Tomcat installed. Within tomcat, I am using Railo (the open source ColdFusion).

I do not want my users dealing with Port 8080 to hit CFM pages. Therefore, I want Apache to render static HTML pages over Port 80 like it normally does, but give way to Tomcat to serve CFM pages *over Port 80*, or however the correct way of saying that is.

Now, I am pretty capable as an administrator for Apache and Unix/Linux. However, I've not had much experience with Tomcat, and while I've got Tomcat and Railo running swimmingly, the only way I've connected it to Apache to allow Port 80 to handle all is with some ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse lines in my Virtual Host definition in Apache.

Part of me feels that this is totally not the right way to do this, and I've had some difficulties finding a clear, recommended approach online. I know there is an Apache Tomcat Connector thing for Tomcat, but that seems to confuse me a bit, and also mentions Tomcat Workers properties, which is something that I dont seem to have in my near-default Tomcat installation.

I know I just wrote a lot but wanted to paint the picture. Any advice would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Jeff

Comment: See the [Railo installation documentation here](https://github.com/getrailo/railo/wiki/Installation:OSX_Tomcat#configuring-apache-with-tomcat) - _Configuring Apache with Tomcat_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mod_proxy (i.e. ProxyPass) is a perfectly acceptable way to do this.

For a much longer answer and discussion of the options see [Tomcat 7 with mod_jk](https://serverfault.com/questions/503834/tomcat-7-with-mod-jk/503857#503857)

Comment: thank you. both this answer and the one below helped me get it working with mod_proxy_ajp. i chose your answer because it also mentions how ajp doesnt support ssl so if I go that route, i'll use one of the other options described in the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this with Railo, but ColdFusion has a mod_jk.conf that needs to be linked from httpd.conf. [This should help with that](http://www.railodeveloper.com/post.cfm/how-to-add-mod-jk-to-apache-for-tomcat-railo).

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [faq#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and **target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future**. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.